# What does an "i" at the end of a regular expression mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i
```

What does `i` at end of a line mean?  I know that `%r` means regular expression, but what is "i" here?

I tried to search on Google at first, but it's really hard to find information about this little thing.

Comment: I had the same question and this was the first Google result.  The formatting is the only possible reason I see for the downvotes so I've proposed an edit to clean it up.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Good call, but you can do even better and use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) when applicable, especially when regexes are involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` modifier means regex will ignore case when matching text. You can read more about other regex modifiers [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html).

```
# with i modifier
%r{.(gif|jpg|png)$}i === ".JpG" #=> true 
%r{.(gif|jpg|png)$}i === ".jpg" #=> true 

# without i modifier
%r{.(gif|jpg|png)$} === ".JpG" #=> false
%r{.(gif|jpg|png)$} === ".jpg" #=> true
```

*Note*: `.` in your regex means 'any single character except newline', not 'dot character'. If you need to match dot character, use backslash to escape it: `\.`

```
%r{.(gif|jpg|png)$} === "ajpg"  # => true
%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$} === "ajpg" # => false
%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$} === ".jpg" # => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby comes with `ri` which is your local copy of the documentation for Ruby.

Open a terminal window or console, and enter `ri Regexp` and you'll get the documentation for Regexp. Read through it and you'll find:

```
== Options

The end delimiter for a regexp can be followed by one or more single-letter
options which control how the pattern can match.

* /pat/i - Ignore case
* /pat/m - Treat a newline as a character matched by .
* /pat/x - Ignore whitespace and comments in the pattern
* /pat/o - Perform #{} interpolation only once

i, m, and x can also be applied on the subexpression level with the
(?on-off) construct, which enables options on, and disables
options off for the expression enclosed by the parentheses.

        /a(?i:b)c/.match('aBc') #=> #
        /a(?i:b)c/.match('abc') #=> #
```